# Limit of a Sum of Functions and Indicators

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

> **Question.** Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be any function. For $n = 1, 2, \dots$ let
>   $$g_n(x) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} f(k/n) \mathbb{1}_A,$$
>
> where $\mathbb{1}_A$ is the indicator function for $A = \left[\frac{k}{n}, \frac{k+1}{n}\right)$.
>
> Show $g_n(c) \to f(c)$ as $n \to \infty$ if there exists some point $c \in \mathbb{R}$ where $f$ is continuous.

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$. We assume $f$ is continuous as some point $c$, and so for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that

$$|x - c| < \delta ~\Rightarrow~ |f(x) - f(c)| < \epsilon.$$

Now we want to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} g_n(c) \to f(c)$.

My idea is to do something like:
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} g_n(c) &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} f(k/n)\mathbb{1}_A \\ 
&= \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \lim_{n \to \infty} f(k/n) \mathbb{1}_A \tag{Continuous at $c$}\\
&= \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} f(0)  \mathbb{1}_{[0, 0)} \\
&\leq \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \frac{\epsilon}{2^k} \\
&= \epsilon.
\end{align}
$$

Im not sure on if my steps from, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} f(k/n)\mathbb{1}_A = \dots \leq \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \frac{\epsilon}{2^k}$, are sufficient? It seems to me you would need to make the extra assumption that $f(c) = f(0)$, so $c = 0$ is this particular point of continuity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: In terms of the greatest integer function $[.]$ we have the simple formula $g_n(x)=f(\frac {[nx]} n)$. If $f$ is continuous at $x$ then, since $\frac {[nx]} n \to x$, we get $g_n(x) \to f(x)$.